# Readme.txt not getting updated

Tags: plugins, wordpress.org

My [readme.txt](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/sharpen-images/trunk/readme.txt) file is not getting updated on the [plugin directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sharpen-images/). Please guide me. Thanks.

```
=== Sharpen Images ===
Contributors: FahadUddinPK
Donate link: Please send donations to ifaqeer@gmail.com (PayPal)
Tags: images, image quality, improve image quality, sharpen images, sharpen jpegs
Requires at least: 3.0.1
Tested up to: 4.4.1
Stable tag: 4.3
License: GPLv2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

Sharpen Images allow you to make jpeg images on the website look sharper, making them look professional and stand out.

== Description ==

Sharpen Images is a WordPress plugin which automatically sharpens resized images for you. You just need to install the plugin and it will sharpen all the jpeg images on the website.</p>
This is the long description.  No limit, and you can use Markdown (as well as in the following sections).

This works fine all versions from 3.0.1 to 4.4.1 which is the latest version.


== Installation ==

This section describes how to install the plugin and get it working.

e.g.

1. Upload the plugin files to the `/wp-content/plugins/sharpen-images` directory, or install the plugin through the WordPress plugins screen directly.
2. Activate the plugin through the 'Plugins' screen in WordPress
3. All of the jpeg's on the website would be sharpen. 


== Frequently Asked Questions ==

= A question that someone might have =

An answer to that question.

= Which type of images does it Sharpen? =

It sharpens only jpeg images.

== Screenshots ==

1. /assets/screenshot-1.png

== Changelog ==
Test


== Upgrade Notice ==



Here's a link to [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/ "Your favorite software") and one to [Markdown's Syntax Documentation][markdown syntax].
Titles are optional, naturally.

[markdown syntax]: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax
            "Markdown is what the parser uses to process much of the readme file"

Markdown uses email style notation for blockquotes and I've been told:
> Asterisks for *emphasis*. Double it up  for **strong**.

`<?php code(); // goes in backticks ?>`
```

Edit:

Apart from the mistakes I had made, WordPress.org is having issues. Here is the email I officially got from them:

```
We are currently experiencing an issue with our systems where plugins cannot be processed properly due to some cache problems. We hope to have this resolved soon.

-Otto
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the `Stable tag` value to your current plugin version `1.0`
2. Make a folder in `tags` with name `1.0`.
3. Copy your plugin files for version `1.0` in that folder with `readme.txt` and push it on SVN.
4. Do the same whenever you release a new version.

*Please note:*
What you keep in your trunk is development version. And defining `Stable tag` in `readme.txt` mean current stable version which will be available for download from all `tags`.

[FAQ](https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/faq/) | [Validate readme.txt](https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/validator/)

Comment: Where do I upload the stable version?

Comment: I followed the instructions. Still facing the same issue. Here is the link to the new readme:
http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/sharpen-images/tags/1.0/readme.txt

Comment: Followed the steps again. The problem is still there..

Comment: I also had the same reply so have patient and cheers!